# Vector representation of time series in Keras stateful LSTM autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I am implementing a `LSTM` autoencoder in Keras to get a vector representation of my time series data.

The series I have are very long and so I am using stateful LSTMs. 
I create non-overlapping windows of each series and input them to the autoencoder.

See code below.

I am unclear of how to get the vector representation of a time series:

1. What is the vector representation of the series? Is it the encoder hidden state or the encoder output?
2. Each sequence is broken into windows and when performing predict, I get an `[encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c]` per window. 
   Which window contains the vector representation of the entire sequence? Is it the last window? The first?

```
# Builing the Model.

inputs = Input(shape=(batch_size,window_size, input_dim))

encoded = LSTM(latent_dim, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=
    (batch_size,window_size, input_dim))(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(window_size)(encoded)

decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, 
    batch_input_shape=(batch_size,window_size, input_dim))(decoded)

decoded = TimeDistributed(Dense(latent_dim, activation='linear')(decoded)
sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)

# Predicting using the encoder
encoded_out=encoder.predict(X, batch_size=batch_size)

# For each sequence in X, we take the output of the last window as the 
    vector representing the entire sequence.

# Is this correct?

seqVector=encoded_out[-batch_size:]
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you mention? It would help to know how you are implementing your autoencoder.

Comment: Your question is too broad. There is no a single answer to the first - you could take either hidden state or last output - or even bought after appropriate transformation. There is no a single answer also to the second question. You could take any aggregation of sequence computations and take it as model representation. All of these decisions are architectural ones and must be taken by an architect of the solution.